# Android: ListView and ArrayAdapter

Tags: java, android, listview, android-listview

so i want to make an app which loads a list with news.
now i did this to create a ListView and an ArrayAdapter:

```
package com.example.MPAK.newsapp;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.example.MPAK.newsapp.R;

import java.util.ArrayList;

public class NewsActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_news);

        ListView lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView);
        String[] values = new String[]{"News1", "NewsTitle2", "NewsTitle3", "NewsTitl4", "NewsTtitle5"};

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            list.add(values[i]);
        }

        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, list);
        lv.setAdapter(adapter);


        lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                        "Click ListItem Number " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
            }
        });


    }



    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.news, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }
        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

the problem is it only shows me the 1st item from my values Array. I dont know why? What did i do wrong?

In the end i want the app to read xml files, read the title, display it on the List. By clicking on the list item it should open a new activity and display the description of the News.
Anyone has some good tutorial for that?

Thanks in advance

Comment: the above code must throw ArrayOutOfIndexException

Comment: Example : http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1659127

Comment: Can you post your layout file? I also want to tell you that you do not need to start activity to display, why not use fragments?

Comment: oh..the 1000 was just a test... it origianlly was i < values.length;   @ Charlesjean i didnt work with fragemtns yet. Would it be better with fragments? The exact workflow should be like this: Login screen->news feed Topics->content of the topics

Comment: layout.xml:<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <ListView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/listView" />
</ScrollView>

Comment: @zooky then change it and post your perfect code.

Comment: Your problem is the ListView inside a ScrollView. The ListView is a scrolling view itself. Take it out of the ScrollView. Also, when providing additional code, layouts, etc., please edit your question to do so. It's hard to read in comments.

Comment: ok nice.Now it works :D I thought that i need a scroll view to get an scrolable list view ;) Does any of you guys have some tutorial how to read out xml files?

Answer (score 0):

```
for (int i = 0; i < values.length; i++) {
        list.add(values[i]);
    }
```

for more informations about xml parsing there is a good tutorial presented by Darek Banas:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=92p6noZjRbk&index=9&list=PLGLfVvz_LVvQUjiCc8lUT9aO0GsWA4uNe

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Kt5wIEF7Lls&list=PLGLfVvz_LVvQUjiCc8lUT9aO0GsWA4uNe&index=10

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=facoiyC7pC8&list=PLGLfVvz_LVvQUjiCc8lUT9aO0GsWA4uNe&index=11

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=SlAHPyNvJ44&index=12&list=PLGLfVvz_LVvQUjiCc8lUT9aO0GsWA4uNe

and there is another good tutorial that is:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=40mYDQkK44A

Comment: This code would help to the OP, but is much better explain why he would use this code.